# Armar un array del tipo data[[clave, Valor], [clave, Valor]...]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy armando un array con los valores dia y venta del dia, en php lo hago asi:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $current_month_sales [$row['day_month']] = $row['total_day'];
            }
```

lo recupero en el evento done de ajax y llega asi:

```
current_month_sales":{
    "6":"59000.49",
    "8":"566300.00",
    "12":"23600.00",
    "13":"6852941.18",
    "14":"8125630.25",
    "16":"6875763.86",
    "17":"6970420.17"}
```

pero lo necesito con este formato para entregarlo a un generador de chart:

```
current_month_sales = [
                [6, 590000.49],
                [8, 566300.00],
                [12, 236000.00],
                [13, 6852941.18],
                [14, 8125630.25],
                [16, 6875763.86],
                [17, 6970420.17]
            ];
```

Y en los dias que no tenga venta, que aparezca el valor en cero (0)

Gacias por sus comentarios.

Comment: por ejemplo si en dia 1 no hubo venta que en el array quede `[1, 0]` pero lLo de los dias en cero no es tan importente puesto que el plugin del chart deja los espacios en blanco, la consulta se hace haciendo un recorrido por la tabla de los dias del mes sumando las ventas de cada dia.
En la respuesta que diste estaba la solucion, por que la borraste?

Comment: Si, mira como llega

`(8) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) [6, "59000.49"]
1: (2) [8, "566300.00"]
2: (2) [12, "23600.00"]
3: (2) [13, "6852941.18"]
4: (2) [14, "8125630.25"]
5: (2) [16, "6875763.86"]
6: (2) [17, "6970420.17"]
7: (2) [18, "590000.00"]
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)`

Asi lo necesitaba, Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una simple comparación y el uso de [`json_encode( )`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) hace el trabajo:

```
$ret = [ ];
while( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
  if( $row['total_day'] > 0 )
    $ret[] = [ $row['day_month'], $row['total_day'] ];

echo json_encode( $ret );
```

Tal y como está, los días **sin ventas** sencillamente **no aparecen** en el `JSON` de resultado.